# How to properly link pre-generated LLVM IR with runtime generated IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

What is the proper way to load a set of pre-generated LLVM IR and make it available to runtime JIT modules such that the same types aren't given new names and inlining and const propagation can still take place?

---

My attempt so far:

I compile those C functions to LLVM IR offline via `clang -c -emit-llvm -S -ffast-math -msse2 -O3 -o MyLib.ll MyLib.c`

For each runtime JIT module, I load the generated LLVM IR via `llvm::parseIRFile()` and "paste" it into the runtime JIT module via `llvm::Linker::linkModules()`.

This works fine for the first JIT module, but not for subsequent JIT modules created. Each time `llvm::parseIRFile()` is called, the resulting module's type definitions in the IR is given new names.

For example, offline MyLib.ll looks like this:

`%struct.A = type { <4 x float> }
 define <4 x float> @Foo(A*)(%struct.A* nocapture readonly)
 {
     ...
 }`

The resulting module from the first call to `llvm::parseIRFile()` looks exactly as the offline version. The resulting module from the **second** call to `llvm:parseIRFile()` instead looks like:

`%struct.A.1 = type { <4 x float> }
 define <4 x float> @Foo(A*)(%struct.A.1* nocapture readonly)
 {
     ...
 }`

Note that `%struct.A` was renamed to `%struct.A.1`. The runtime JIT module continues to generate code using `%struct.A` thus fails to call `Foo()` since it takes `%struct.A.1` instead.